# Help need to setup a Ruby on Rails App stack using docker

Tags: docker, ruby, container

I have setup a Rails app on a docker container and a apache web server on another container. I need the apache web server to access the rails app for every request made. The issue is I have to configure and compile phusion passenger which links the Rails app to the apache binary which I am not able to do.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: it is difficult to resolve the problem with compiling the software until you say why you are unable to compile the software

Comment: I want to compile the software which in interacts with binaries present in both the containers, but the containers are isolated from each other. How do I make sure the file system in one container is shared with another.

Comment: A Docker volume might work for your use case: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers